# How to avoid animated element expanding the page when it scales up

Tags: html, css

I want to place the css animation so it only shows partially on the page.
My problem is that it keeps expanding the page.
I have tried using overflow hidden on .ripple-background but this doesn't work. I have also tried using clip but I don't think this is the right  solution unless I am using it wrong.
Can anyone shed some light for me please!

```css
.ripple-background {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 610px;
    width: 610px;
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-top: 50vh;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    animation: ripple 25s infinite;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #b1b1b1;

}

.small {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.medium {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
 
}

.large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }

.xlarge {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.xxlarge {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.shade1 {
    opacity: 1;
}

.shade2 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.shade3 {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.shade4 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.shade5 {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}
```

```html
 <!-- Animation -->
  <div class="ripple-background">
    <div class="circle xxlarge shade1"></div>
    <div class="circle xlarge shade2"></div>
    <div class="circle large shade3"></div>
    <div class="circle medium shade4"></div>
    <div class="circle small shade5"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Animation END-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For overflow hidden to work, you need it to be on a parent container, with the content inside of it that you want to hide.

Below, I've created a wrapper and set it to be the size of the page.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.ripple-background {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: -1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 610px;
    width: 610px;
    margin-left: 60%;
    margin-top: 50vh;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    animation: ripple 25s infinite;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #b1b1b1;

}

.small {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.medium {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
 
}

.large {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }

.xlarge {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.xxlarge {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.shade1 {
    opacity: 1;
}

.shade2 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.shade3 {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.shade4 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.shade5 {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

@keyframes ripple {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Animation -->
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class="ripple-background">
    <div class="circle xxlarge shade1"></div>
    <div class="circle xlarge shade2"></div>
    <div class="circle large shade3"></div>
    <div class="circle medium shade4"></div>
    <div class="circle small shade5"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Animation END-->
```